# Shell script to send notification to users using email id fetch it from database

Tags: shell

Can someone help me with the shell script - fetching cntct_email from user table on oracle database on some condition and sending email notification to all those users.

```
user_list1=$(echo -ne "set heading OFF\n select cntct_email from user where 
xprtn_dt = SYSDATE - 60;" | sqlplus -s ${ORA_UID_PSWD})
printf "Hi,\nFYI Your password is expired 60 days ago. Please login and get it 
reset..\n\nThanks,\n Team" |mailx -s "Password expired" $user_list1
```

I tried using the above code but it's not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include as much detail as possible when asking a question. Please provide the table structure which you are trying to read from as well as the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the below :

```
query=$(sqlplus -s ${ORA_UID_PSWD} << 'EOF'
set heading OFF
select cntct_email from user where xprtn_dt = SYSDATE - 60;
EOF
)
user_list1=$(echo "$query" | tr '\n' ',')
echo -e "Hi,\nFYI Your password is expired 60 days ago. Please login and get it reset..\n\nThanks,\n Team" |mailx -s "Password expired" $user_list1
```

Comment: Hi funkyjelly, This works for xprtn_dt > SYSDATE - 60, but not for xprtn_dt = SYSDATE - 60. Since xprtn_dt has time stamp along with date, it's trying to match exact date and time. Any way that we can remove time and it should compare only date?

Comment: @Mansur you can try using the trunc() function, eg `xprtn_dt = trunc(SYSDATE) - 60`

Comment: and if needed you can also add `trunc(xprtn_dt)`

Comment: Just one more question, When I display mail id's, they have been in comma(,) separated which is good, but first it will start with comma and then it will start displaying mail id's. Any way to get rid of first comma(,)